# How to run Python tests against multiple Python conda environments?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, conda, tox

I have a few carefully configured `conda` environments created using Anaconda. I have written a Python package that uses some of the packages and libraries installed in these environments. Now I would like to run the tests with each test file being executed for each environment to make sure the package can handle working with different Python versions and different set of 3rd party packages available.

Using a `tox` did not work for me because it tries to recreate those environments locally to run tests against. This is how my `tox.ini` file looks:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36, py27
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
basepython = 
    py36: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Env1\python.exe
    py27: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Env2\python.exe

commands = 
    {envpython} -m unittest discover
```

However, it is not possible to do just plain `pip install` into the environments `tox` creates on each run mainly because there are some compiled libraries and workarounds involved (which are solved in a `conda` environment - so I have to use those as they are).

I currently have a dummy `.bat` file with the following content:

```
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Env1\python.exe" -m unittest discover
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Env2\python.exe" -m unittest discover
```

which I execute in a Windows `cmd` to see the results. It does work, but I wonder whether there is any more Pythonic way to run these tests such using `py.test` or `tox`. I do not want to recreate the `conda` environments I already have; I just want to use different Python interpreters accessed at different locations to run my tests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555943/is-it-possible-to-use-tox-with-conda-based-python-installations

Comment: Thanks, worth digging into. Any non `tox` solutions are welcome, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into pytest-xdist [plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/). It allows you to run tests across different python environments.

Usage:

```
pytest --dist=each --tx popen//python=python3.5 --tx popen//python=python2.7
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, great tool. Where will this plugin read the paths to the Python installations? From tox.ini files? Or is there any other way to define those? The docs https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist#running-tests-in-a-python-subprocess do not seem to tell anything on this...

Comment: It does not require tox.ini file. Python2 and Python3 should be present in the environment and all the dependencies must be installed in both python2 and python3. Having both python2 and python3 in a virtual environment may be tricky. I would suggest you to try the command without python virtual environment.
These commands seem to run tests for me.
>python2 --version
>python3 --version
>pip2 install -r requirements.txt
>pip3 install -r requirements.txt
>pytest --dist=each --tx popen//python=python3 --tx popen//python=python2

Comment: thanks for getting back. How do I specify paths to conda environments? Could you elaborate on what do you mean by `Python2 and Python3 should be present in the environment `? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have experience with conda. I use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper for python env management. I use pip for package management. Conda may be handling packages and envs differently.

Comment: OK, I see. So, when you write `python=python3.5` how does `pytest` know where to search for `python.exe` file for this particular environment?

Comment: If python3.5 exists in system path, it will run fine.

Comment: Use this answer to create multiple env https://stackoverflow.com/a/30555944/2312300