# How does a tox environment set its sys.path

Tags: python, tox

I have a Python project that requires some compilation. `tox` makes the `sdist` and the `bdist_wheel` successfully. But when `tox` runs the tests, the source code module is always the one that get imported, causing the tests to fail (because there are no binaries there). This happens because the root of the project is always the first folder on `sys.path` and I cannot figure out how this happens.

```
project
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.c <-- turns into bar.so in bdist_wheel
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_bar.py
├── tox.ini
└── setup.py
```

### `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist =
    py37

[testenv]
changedir = {toxinidir}/tests
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {envsitepackagesdir}
commands = {envpython} -m pytest --cov=bar --cov-report=html
```

Note that I set `changedir` to ensure that the project root is not the working directory. I also set `PYTHONPATH` to only the tox environment's site-packages. I also force the tox environment's Python to be run.

Nevertheless, this is `sys.path` I see if I print it out during test running:

```
[
  '/home/me/foo', # Bad, bad, bad
  '/home/me/foo/tests', # Good, this is the CWD
  '/home/me/foo/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages', # Good
  '/home/me/foo/.tox/py37/lib/python37.zip', # Umm, ok, this doesn't exist
  '/home/me/foo/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7', # Good
  '/home/me/foo/.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', # Probably good
  '/home/me/anaconda/envs/foo/lib/python3.7',  # Bad, why is this here?
]
```

The biggest offender is `/home/me/foo` which causes the source module `foo` to be loaded instead of the one installed in `tox`.

Another problematic one is `/home/me/anaconda/envs/foo/lib/python3.7`. I would prefer that `tox` not fall back on the system interpreter if something is not found in the environment.

How does tox choose this these paths and how do I control it to be better behaved?

Comment: Any warnings or something unusual in tox output? virtualenv present? https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/273 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555943/is-it-possible-to-use-tox-with-conda-based-python-installations suggest that tox doesn't play well with Anaconda.

Comment: `tox` does not give any warnings all, and yes, I am using Anaconda.

Answer (score 5):

This is not caused by tox; it is caused by pytest. [As described in the pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code), there is known to be a bad interaction between pytest and tools like tox that install the distribution in an isolated environment.

The reason for this is that [pytest modifies `sys.path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html) so that all folders containing test packages (test folders with `__init__.py` in them) are added to it. Because the `foo/tests` directory contains a `__init__.py` file, pytest adds `foo/` to `sys.path` so that the `tests` package can be imported with the normal `import` statement.

[Even removing `__init__.py` may not be enough.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html#invoking-pytest-versus-python-m-pytest) Running pytest as `python -m pytest` in the `foo` directory will cause the `foo` directory to be added to `sys.path`. Running pytest with the `pytest` command line tool will avoid this.

The recommended solution is to move all source to a dedicated `src` directory. This ensures that the source packages will never be on `sys.path` even if the project root is.

## Recommended project structure

```
project
├── src
│   └── foo
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── bar.c
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_bar.py
├── tox.ini
└── setup.py
```